# Using wireless router to connect the computers to a printer

Tags: wireless-networking, printer

I have a TP-Link N600 wireless router. The individual laptops are in a office network. How can i connect a single printer to these laptops(wirelessly) without having to pay for a static IP for the printer? The printer is not wireless and so I was thinking of the using the Router. But not sure how to go about it as I am not a hardware person. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I am not quite sure about your question, are you trying to connect to the printer through the internet? If you are talking about a local environment I don't think you have to pay for a static IP.

If it is indeed a local network, the idea I have in mind is to connect the printer using a LAN cable to the router and assign an IP to the printer (e.g. `192.168.1.100`). Then setup the wireless in your router, and make sure the IP the router allocates is in the same subnet (assuming subnet is `255.255.255.0`) as the printer (so the assigned IPs will need to be `192.168.1.x` as well, e.g. `192.168.1.101`). Then assuming your router is not blocking any traffic between the two, your office workstations should be able to at least ping the printer.

If you are talking about printing through the internet. The only safe way I could think of is to use a VPN connection to connect back to your office LAN. You router will need to support the VPN server function. Once the VPN connection is established and assuming the VPN IP is in the same subnet as the printer, the printing should then work.

Answer (score 0):

Please advise your printer model.

It is possible to connect the printer via a USB port on the router, but that depends to a large extent on the printer model. It may not work with some (cheaper) printer models.

In the meantime, start by reading this page:
http://www.tp-link.com/en/faq-415.html